# Anchor tag not clickable only in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Below is the simple html file, contains an anchor, overlay by block element with certain style. After applying the styles, the link become non-clickable only in IE9. Style applied is to make the anchor muted but allow users to click, if needed. Tried different options by using Jquery, didn't worked out. Any hack for this in html/css?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Trial</title>
    <style>
    .overlay {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
        pointer-events: none;
    }       
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">ClickMe</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: using `pointer-events: none;` would null out click(pointer) events in IE9

Comment: Does it work when you remove the pointer-events property?

Comment: @EricHolmes Wrong. `pointer-events:none` ["instructs the mouse event to go "through" the element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS property `pointer-events` is not supported in < IE11 (See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)

As a work-around you *could* use JavaScript to listen for a click on the overlay and then trigger the click on the link underneath if its under your cursor. Something like:

```
function simulateClick(el) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    el.dispatchEvent(evt);
};
function isOnTopOf(evt, el) {
    return evt.clientX >= el.offsetLeft && evt.clientX <= el.offsetLeft+el.offsetWidth && evt.clientY >= el.offsetTop && evt.clientY <= el.offsetTop+el.offsetHeight;
};          

var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
var clicker = document.getElementById("clicker");

overlay.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if(isOnTopOf(evt, clicker)){
        simulateClick(clicker);
    }
}, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nxdm5x3u/

**However** if your entire reason for doing this is to make the link appear "muted" you could just use CSS to make it semi-transparent and not bother with the overlay:

```
a.muted {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

Comment: Any feedback re the down-vote? Is this not well-formed? Is it invalid? does it not meet the OP's requirements? ANYTHING that would help me improve my answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Teemu. Hi. What CSS trick is that? I'm not setting the background at all. I wasn't aware that IE did that. Are you suggesting that the overlay is given a background:transparent and is made semi-opaque through other means? If so, perhaps you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Looks like I've mixed the codes, removed the comment.